# contact collection - php, mysql, mail server

Tags: php, email, crm, mail-server

I am building a project assuming that there is a method for intercepting incoming and outgoing mail from a mailserver.  If it is not possible please let me know, I am new working with mail servers, so any material that you could provide would be greatly appreciated.

---

I am building a project to manage contacts and the organization's interaction with them throughout a broad range of services.  I would like the creation of the contacts be as automatic as possible.  In this sense, what I had thought would be interesting was to create a page that would intercept all incoming and outgoing message from the org.'s mailserver. The intercepted data would be stored on a MySQL database.

**Is this possible in PHP? Would this be the correct way of going about it?**

What I'm looking for is a place to start looking and learning. Reading materials, tutorials, case-studies, etc. Whatever you can send over to help me get closer to my goal. Also, if the method I've described above is flawed, or you can recommend a better method, I'd be willing to hear your thoughts on that as well.

Comment: there is a technical solution. but intercepting/reading someone else's mail is a moral/ethical issue.

Comment: What kind of mailservers are you working with? It's quite likely the mailserver software has some facilities that would make this easier than listening in on the network and parsing out the addresses yourself.

Comment: i am interested in the technical solution. "intercepting" is a scary word, but the intent is not to create a spy app. the organization is small and everyone works together. i want everyone to have access to the same information: who has been contacted by whom, what has been sent to whom, etc. stillstanding - can you provide some help?

Comment: #bobdiaes: I am using a pop3/smtp mail server.

Answer (score 0):

If so have a look at PHP's IMAP functions as they provide everything you need to be able to do this quite easily.

Have a look at http://www.php.net/manual/en/ref.imap.php and ask any specific questions about the functions used you may have.